# HTML5 - Initiate Game Objects that Share Same Variable

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

I'm just wondering whats the best way to initiate the same objects that all share the same variables, except their positions.

I'm basically working on the scene of my HTML5 game, and I've build a streetlamp post that turns on and off. All the lamps will have the same variables, such as Image, Size, on/off function. The only thing that will be different will be the position x and y.

I've built my lamp within a variable function (I think they're called that 'var = {'), and within my actual game DrawFunction, I'm calling 'LampPost.draw();'.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
LampPost(0,0);
LampPost(100, 0);
LampPost(200, 0);
```

etc ... and then possibly place each initiated Lamp within an array?

This is a snippet code for the lamp:

```
var LampPost = {

    lamp_xsprite : 0,
    lamp_ysprite : 0,

    light_xsprite : 0,
    lightysprite : 0,

    x : 440,
    y : 320,

    //Flicker effects
    lightFlicker : 0,
    seconds_Off : 0,
    seconds_On : 0,

    randomLength_Off : 500,
    randomLength_On : 150,


    draw: function(x, y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        ctxPropsOver.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -Map.x + gameWidth/2, -Map.y + gameHeight/2);
        ctxPropsOver.rotate(Math.PI / -25);
        ctxPropsOver.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

        ctxPropsOver.globalAlpha = this.lightFlicker;
        ctxPropsOver.drawImage(imgLights, 0, 36, 500, 463, -60 + this.x, -190 + this.y, 500, 463);
        ctxPropsOver.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctxPropsOver.drawImage(imgLights, 0, 0, 210, 36, 0 + this.x, 0 + this.y, 210, 36);

        this.flicker();

    }
};
```

Comment: I'd use JSON to represent the state of the game and separate it from the code.

Comment: Use prototypical inheritance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 common ways of achieving your goal: a factory function or a constructor function with a prototype.  The factory function is fairly simple to understand, you basically take the code you have now, and throw it into a function as a return statement.

```
function LampPost(x, y) {
   var lampPost = {
        lamp_xsprite: 0,
        lamp_ysprite: 0,

        light_xsprite: 0,
        lightysprite: 0,

        x: x, //Reference x argument here
        y: y, //Reference y argument here

        //Flicker effects
        lightFlicker: 0,
        seconds_Off: 0,
        seconds_On: 0,

        randomLength_Off: 500,
        randomLength_On: 150,


        draw: function(x, y) { /* Cut for readability */ }
    };

    globalLampPostArray.push(lampPost);

    return lampPost;
}
```

This, however, has the downside of making a new draw function (and presumably flicker function) for each copy of LampPost that is made.  The other way that allows you to have just one copy of each function is to use a constructor function with a prototype.

```
function LampPost(x, y) {

    //Make sure LampPost is called as a constructor
    if(!this instanceof LampPost) {
        return new LampPost(x, y);
    }

    this.lamp_xsprite = 0;
    this.lamp_ysprite = 0;

    this.light_xsprite = 0;
    this.lightysprite = 0;

    this.x = x; //Reference x argument here
    this.y = y; //Reference y argument here

    //Flicker effects
    this.lightFlicker = 0;
    this.seconds_Off = 0;
    this.seconds_On = 0;

    this.randomLength_Off = 500;
    this.randomLength_On = 150;

    globalLampPostArray.push(this);
}

LampPost.prototype.draw = function(x, y) {
    /* Draw function code */
}

LampPost.prototype.flicker = function() {
    /* Flicker code */
}
```

Now each copy of lamp post will reference the same draw and flicker functions, which also has the bonus of being able to redefine behavior across all of them OR for only one instance.  The beginning of this version has a check to make sure it was called as a constructor.  In order to use the prototype properties a function must be called with the **new** keyword.  This just ensures all calls to LampPost will return a new instance of LampPost.

Also note at the end of each function I [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) each instance into an array for future reference, as that was also part of your question.  This lets you do this:

```
function drawLampPosts() {
    for (var i = 0, len = globalLampPostArray.length; i < n; i++) {
        globalLampPostArray[i].draw();
    };
}
```

Although, you might as well have an array that contains all of your drawable game objects (rather than just one for lamp posts) and just do it in one loop.